# How can I resolve “server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client”

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I have three servers:

```
1 master: 192.168.1.131 k8s
1 node: 192.168.1.132 k8s
1 rancher: 192.168.1.133 rancher 2.6
```

I have created a docker image (private registry docker) on the node used `192.168.1.132:5000/test.`
Both master and node pushed and pulled to the image. But used rancher deploy set image 192.168.1.132:5000/test then error:

```
Failed to pull image “192.168.1.132:5000/test-demo”: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image “192.168.1.132:5000/test-demo:latest”: failed to resolve reference “192.168.1.132:5000/test-demo:latest”: failed to do request: Head “https://192.168.1.132:5000/v2/test-demo/manifests/latest”: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client.
```

My image used
`http` not `https`. But the rancher sends HTTPS.
[This is image problem](https://ibb.co/t2wxbQ8)

Comment: you can set global default registry and specify the protocol https://docs.ranchermanager.rancher.io/v2.5/how-to-guides/advanced-user-guides/authentication-permissions-and-global-configuration/global-default-private-registry

Comment: @Adiii my problem is, my image use http, but rancher call https from header.

Comment: check the step 4 in the link Change the value to your registry (e.g. registry.yourdomain.com:port). Do not prefix the registry with http:// or https://.

Comment: @Adiii, I have changed, but not working after restart everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this out by adding one line to the **daemon.json** file

The configuration file can be found at ***'C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json'***. You can create this file if it doesn't already exist.

```
"insecure-registries": [
    "192.168.1.132:5000"
]
```

Then restart the docker service hope solves the issue.

Raff:

1. [Configure the Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon)
2. [Configure Docker with a configuration file.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#configure-docker-with-a-configuration-file)